# IntelliJ IDEA gradle project setup

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

What is the best procedure for beginning a new Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3?

I created a skeleton `build.gradle` file with the idea plugin to generate the project files:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}
```

When I open the new project IntelliJ complains that the `Groovy SDK is not configured for module`:

[image: Groovy SDK is not configured for module 'gradle']

After configuring the Groovy SDK I get Java inspection issues in the build file:

[image: java.sql.Wrapper? (multiple choices...) Alt+Enter]

Am I doing something wrong or is this normal for a Gradle based project in IDEA?  Should I just disable inspection?

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to import a skeleton project and IDEA automatically configured everything properly.  However I am still receiving Java inspection errors in `build.gradle` as shown above.

[image: Build #IU-129.451]

Answer (score 3):

If you use Gradle's `idea` task to generate project files, this is normal, as there is no way to tell IDEA what the class path of the build script itself is. If you instead use IDEA's Gradle integration ("Import from Gradle model"), this problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Importing a clean project structure with a `build.gradle` and task wrapper worked great.  However I still have inspection issues in the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Maybe you aren't using the latest IDEA version?

Comment: I'm on the latest available non-EAP version as updated above.

Comment: how do I provide IDEAs Gralde Integration with additional information, like enable APT?

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked anout a year ago for IDEA 12, and at that time the Gradle support was still... let's say "in progress". In the meantime IDEA 13 is out, and the Gradle support plugin has improved dramatically. See this (short) video for the current capabilities: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3Euo6xzCwY4 It isn't a stupid menu walkthrough, it is a concrete example.