# Intellij IDEA and Gradle projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a new project. Should I place `apply plugin: 'idea'` in `build.gradle` and run `$ gradle idea`? Or should I import the gradle project directly into IntelliJ IDEA 14.1? Which one will allow me to add dependencies to `build.gradle` and have IDEA automatically download & know about them?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With Intellij 14 you can just open the the `build.gradle` file using Intellij's **File --> Open**. this will import the gradle project, including all dependencies.
After you change something in the `build.gradle` file, you can click on "refresh all gradle projects" at the top of the gradle tool window.

You may also mark "use auto-import" under the *Build Tools/Gradle* tab in Settings. This will resolve all changes made to the gradle project automatically every time you refresh your project.

The idea plugin is the old method of importing a gradle project into Intellij.
With the newer versions of Intellij, it has become redundant.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to enable auto-import using Gradle. Syncing gradle and IntelliJ takes a few seconds (much longer than with Maven), and you don't want to watch IntelliJ doing this after every few keystrokes.

Comment: Oh - just today, Gradle 2.4 was released, with a significantly improved performance. Maybe it's getting better :)

Comment: BTW you can speed up gradle with 
`echo "org.gradle.daemon=true" > ~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Answer (score 7):

From my experience using the `idea` plugin does not always work correctly in IntelliJ and actually [IntelliJ documentation guidelines](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-gradle-model.html) are to simply import build.gradle file.

Also, [Peter Niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser) who is a [Principal Software Engineer at Gradleware](https://gradlesummit.com/conference/speaker/peter_niederwieser) answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001759/intellij-idea-gradle-project-setup) ~2 years ago mentioning the following:

> If you use Gradle's idea task to generate project files, this is normal, as there is no way to tell IDEA what the class path of the build script itself is. If you instead use IDEA's Gradle integration ("Import from Gradle model"), this problem doesn't exist.

Bottom line, your safer way to go would be importing gradle project directly from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Gradle Project in IntelliJ, and it will handle all of the dependencies and integrate well with Gradle. You can [see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle.html) for more info and specifics.