# For IntelliJ, is there ANY reason to import Eclipse project vs. just importing the Gradle project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I have seen many questions about importing Eclipse or Gradle projects into IntelliJ, but not a question asking which approach to use. I assume just import Gradle?

We use Eclipse over Gradle, I can build and run my projects either with gradle command lines or (less likely:) in Eclipse. As long as I can build with gradle on the command line my boss is happy.

[I found the fully-enabled free student versions of IntelliJ/Jetbrains products,](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/) so I am using the Ultimate version 15.02. Gradle 2.8 FWIW.

Is there ANY reason to import the Eclipse project vs. just importing the Gradle project? And I guess in the last couple versions of IntelliJ [you just open the Gradle file, not import a Gradle project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041281/intellij-idea-and-gradle-projects)

Also still a good idea to leave auto-import turned off? And I notice putting apply plugin: 'idea'; in build.gradle [is no longer necessary since version 14.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041281/intellij-idea-and-gradle-projects?lq=1)

Comment: How would one quantify "better"?  What difference can you tell in the final project contents?  Gradle and Maven offer more than the mere Eclipse project: You can use either one to build and manage your project.

Comment: I will edit out "better" the question is "is there ANY reason" not what is better thanks for helping me improve the question. I was only showing I had searched SO for this answer and didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in the differences from importing from Eclipse vs Gradle, but I would always import from Gradle when possible (this is true for Maven and Ant base builds as well).

Which datastructure do you want Intellij to use to figure out where your sources are? You can either use the same thing Eclipse used (the build.gradle file) or you can use the product of Eclipse's interpretation of the build.gradle file.

When you import from Eclipse, you're essentially saying "Instead of getting my information direct from the build tool's setup, I'm going to get my information that got its information from the build tool." You've added another layer for no real value in the import.

That said, maybe there are things that the Eclipse project settings that project import will include. I could imagine the Eclipse project import pulling in anything like manually included jars, but this means that your project probably requires an IDE to build it (which is terrible) and really you should refactor your project so that it can be built without any IDE assistance (from the command line).

So in short, import from Gradle directly. Don't go through Eclipse. You're just filtering the source data through a filter that isn't adding any value. Or if it is adding value, then it's probably a project specific configuration that shouldn't be done in an IDE anyways.

PS.

I always just go to the build.gradle file and "open" that. Same thing for pom.xml.

I always have auto-import on, both for Maven and Gradle based projects. I've never run into any issues with it and it keeps me coding faster.

Comment: I like your answer overall but use of words  "maybe" and "imagine" leaving me thinking there is a more authoritative answer coming :) I agree that intuitively it seems smarter to bypass Eclipse. Just wondering if there's ANY upside to importing eclipse project vs. gradle project. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know, this is a fairly old question, but I just wondered the same thing.

Apparently, JetBrains recommends importing the build tool file instead of the Eclipse project when possible.

> If your project uses a build tool such as Maven or Gradle, we recommend choosing the corresponding option when prompted in the Import Project wizard, and selecting the associated build file (pom.xml or build.gradle) [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html#migratingEclipseProject)